# How will the change in IPV6 impact existing web applications?

Tags: networking

Anyone have any ideas e.g for ip addresses that are currently stored in application configuratio files etc do they need to be changed

Comment: your point isn't specific to web apps.  But, in general, unless are requried do, fully qualified domain names are how you should refer to other hosts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking about the only impact that I know of is if you specify IP Addresses in your existing web applications, you have to change the ranges to accomodate IPv6.

The first thing to do would be search your code for any references to System.Net.IPAddress, and see how you're passing information around in those areas:

- Are you performing any "manual" validation that expects IP addresses
  to be in the IPv4 format?
- Do you have any UI components, in the application itself or
  any configuration tools/pages you have for it that are hard-coded to
  an xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx format?
- How much space do you allocate to store IP addresses in things such
  as logging tables in databases? 15 characters is ample for an IPv4
  address, but an IPv6 address can be considerably bigger.
- Do you display IP addresses anywhere in your UI? If you do, do you
  allocate enough screen real-estate to show a full IPv6 address?

There are other questions to answer but they're more infrastructure related and serverfault would be a better place for them.

[Making an asp.net application IPv6 compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442141/making-an-asp-net-application-ipv6-compliant)